# How to I determine aar file after build

Tags: android, apk

I am building an apk file for android in visual studio with cordova. To this end I am including an aar file. 
I also have an older version of the apk file I am looking at and want to find out what aar file was used to build the apk, how is this done?

I have opened the apk, and the file itself is not present. A textual search on the name of the aar also reveals nothing,

Answer (score 1):

You can use a decompiler to have all the packages and information listed

I use this one usually: https://github.com/skylot/jadx

You just need to build it locally with these commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/skylot/jadx.git
cd jadx
./gradlew dist
```

A `build` folder will be generated.

Go inside `jadx/build/jadx/bin`

Copy the APK inside the bin folder for simplicity and launch from terminal:

```
jadx-gui name_of_apk.apk
```

Then a GUI will open with all the informations you need

Comment: thanks, but the source aar is nowhere to be found, nor any reference I can use to determine the actual version of it

Comment: Have you tried searching in Resources/META-INF folder to see if there is a file with aar version? (i dont remember exactly if there is a way to get the exact version of an aar)
Maybe you can manually check some lines of code which you know is different between different library versions. (You could use a tagged git version to get differences easier)

Comment: there is no reference to an aar file at all

Comment: So you need to proceed with the second approach I mentioned in the comment. It's slower but it's your only chance apparently